# move_uploaded_file does not working on windows server

Tags: php, file-upload, windows-server

I know this question is so common in stackoverflow and many questions are available on this topic, but still I did not match any answer solving my **strange** prblem.

```
$path = "img/"
$tmp = $_FILES ['footer-bg-img'] ['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file ( $tmp, $path . $actual_image_name );
```

its working fine on my local system both `WAMP` and `XAMPP` application, but on my windows web server it returns `false`, which makes me strange, on my web server I printed the function output, it gives me

> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\phpAA55.tmp" string(21)
>   "/img/20131208_bjp.jpg" bool(false) dead

I have asked the service provider to give the `img` folder 0777 permission, they told me they have done that. But having still same problem, now should I contact the service provider or there could be coding error, please suggest.

Comment: Change img/ to img\ . Also you can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to make your code work on multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

I still think its a permissions issue. Please have a look at the following topic: [move_uploaded_file() returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638872/move-uploaded-file-returns-false)

You can also check the permissions to the directory with PHP function:

```
if ( ! is_writeable ( $path ) )
{
    echo 'Can\'t write to directory, insufficient permissions.';
}
```

Comment: thank you @Scriptman, the folder is not writeable, is there any way to make the folder writeable on serverside.

Comment: As mentioned in the provided StackOverflow topic, you may need to add the IIS_IUSR to the directory. Your hosting provider should fix that for you.